# map and fixed side bar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to do a simple version of something like this: http://techlist.in/
Basically, I want to have a map and a right side bar with a fixed size and fixed position.

I've started with something like:

HTML:

```
...
<div class="container">
  <div class="span10">
    <div id="map_canvas">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span2" style="position:fixed; right:0">
    Some stuff
  </div>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
#map_canvas {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-top:40px; /* used for the top navigation bar */
}
```

But this is not working as expected, as the map remains 100% width and the "some stuff" label appears on top of the map. Any hints?

**UPDATE**

In fact, I already have the nav-bar, but I did not detailed it in the code, my bad. So basically the whole structure of the html page is (with the missing row div added):

```
<body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
      ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span10">
        <div id="map_canvas">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2" style="position:fixed; right:0">
        Some stuff
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- include javascript stuff -->
  ...

</body>
```

The css file is:

```
#map_canvas {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  height: 90%
  width: 80%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-right:200px;/* used for the top navigation bar */
  background: #ccc;
}
```

If a leave 200px of right margin for the map, how can I fill the margin with the sidebar ?

Basically, I need a side bar of 200px width and the map adapting accordingly on screen resizing.

**UPDATE 3**

I'm wondering if I really need to use container / row to achieve this layout in fact (I still do not manage to have this working as expected). As I only need to have a map and a sidebar (that should always remain on the right of the map even if the window is resized), would it make some sense to use basic div / css and not bootstrap classes ?

This is basically what I needed: http://jsfiddle.net/kuXYq/4/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this fiddle I made it might help.

[http://jsfiddle.net/eKQGD/](http://jsfiddle.net/eKQGD/1/)

I used percentages to keep things the same

```
    #map_canvas {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  height: 90%
  width: 80%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-right:150px;/* used for the top navigation bar */
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some additional details. How would you set the sidebar so it stays in the 150px (margin) left by the map ?

Comment: just set the width of your sidebar to the gap so in this case 150px;

Comment: though a word of warning then when you zoom out the map will get bigger and the sidebar get smaller!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to the answer to this question.

- The first thing to point out is that it's a little hazy as to why there is the requirement of a "fixed size and position", and by that I mean that the terminology being used may be throwing off your thinking a bit.  Typically, you only need to use the "fixed" css position property if you plan on the page having scroll bars and you want the element to stay in the same position on the page no matter what.  In this case, it doesn't seem like you want page scrolling at all since the map will appear to be the same size as the entire page.  It seems like what you really want on the sidebar is for it to be a fixed height (aka the height of the browser window) with overflow set to scroll.
- Secondly, it appears that you're missing a `<div class="row"></div>` tag around your elements - a tag with a "row" class is necessary to make the bootstrap "span" classes work.
- Lastly, here is something that I would go with if I was trying to duplicate the link you posted, using a bit of JS love as well: http://jsfiddle.net/kzBkA/5/ (background colors added just to show what it looks like )

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span10">
        <div id="nav_bar">
            Nav bar goes here
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas">
            test
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
          <div id="sidebar">
              Some stuff
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#nav_bar {
    height:40px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#map_canvas {
    background-color:green;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    $("#map_canvas").height($(window).height() - 40);
    $("#sidebar").height($(window).height());
});
```

UPDATE:

So - again, first off, I encourage you to reconsider your use of fixed elements.  You seem to be trying to build a page that won't scroll, but then using a "positioning" feature that's specifically for scrolling (position:fixed), which basically tells all your nice bootstrap code to be ignored and just put it where you tell it.  A much nicer way to do this would be to use Bootstrap to your advantage.  I changed the row class to row-fluid, I moved your nav bar into the span10 with the map (since that's how wide you actually want the nav, or at least that's how it was in the example), I removed the "navbar-fixed-top" class since you don't actually need things to be fixed, and removed the fixed positioning from the sidebar (since again that's basically making it ignore what you're trying to do).  Check out the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzBkA/7/ - you may have to tinker with the JS to get the map_canvas div set with the correct height, but otherwise this should take care of making your page fluid when the browser is resized without having to add a ton of unnecessary CSS rules.  In general, if you use a scaffolding framework, you should use it to your advantage to avoid creating cluttered, messy css with lots of "`width:80%; height:20%; margin: ...`"  - the whole point of using the framework and scaffolding was to *avoid* that kind of code :)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span10">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                navbar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas">
            map goes here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2" id="sidebar">
        Some stuff
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    max-width:100%;
}

#map_canvas {
    background-color:green;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#map_canvas").height($(window).height() - 40);
    $("#sidebar").height($(window).height());
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just realized I missed the part about the sidebar always being 200px but the map width being fluid.  I've updated the fiddle to reflect that as well as updating so that sizes get reset when window is resized - http://jsfiddle.net/kzBkA/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span10 left-col">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                navbar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas">
            map goes here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 right-col" id="sidebar">
        Some stuff
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    max-width:100%;
}

#map_canvas {
    background-color:green;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.right-col{
    width:200px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    resizeElements();
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        resizeElements();
    }
});

function resizeElements(){
    //set height
    $("#map_canvas").height($(document).height() - $(".navbar").outerHeight() - 20 /*not sure where this is coming from, possibly the scrollbar?*/);
    $("#sidebar").height($(document).height());

    //set width of left col
    $(".left-col").width($(document).width() - $(".right-col").outerWidth() - 20 /*not sure where this is coming from, possibly the scrollbar?*/)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have updated the question as I forgot to add some details on the top nav bar.

Comment: It's working fine on jsfiddle but I have some big problems when running directly in Chrome: the red column appears below and the map's height keeps increasing each time I resize the window. I'll check this and make an update.